# Git Bash / curl: How to print results; I only get "Total, Received, Xferd..."

Tags: git, bash, curl, grep

I am running Git Bash and using the **curl** and **grep** commands as follows:

```
curl httP://www.url.com |grep -i class=\"ip\" |cut -d ’/’ -f 3 \
|cut -d ’"’ -f 1|uniq >db.ip
```

The output I get is:

```
"%Total (143).... %Received....%Xferd... Average Speed...." and so on.
```

However, I would like to see **the 143 actual results**. Can someone please help? THANKS!

I run Windows 7, 64bit.

Comment: `uniq | grep -oP 'Total\s+\(\K\d+' > db.ip`

Comment: Hi Avinash, thanks. I get the following error though: **"grep: invalid option -o"**

Answer (score 0):

You may use sed,

```
... | uniq | sed 's/Total *(\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' > db.ip
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get **"cut: invalid request code"**. Why might this happen?